# web2py KeyError on using CascadingSelect

Tags: web2py, cascadingdropdown, keyerror

I am trying to use the CascadingSelect available [here](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1410/cascading-drop-down-lists), but get `<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>`. My models are as below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
db.define_table('bank_master',
            Field('name'),
            format='%(name)s'
            )

db.define_table('bank_branch',
            Field('bank', db.bank_master),
            Field('name'),
            format='%(name)s'
            )
db.define_table('case_master',
            Field('case_number'),
            Field('bank_branch', db.bank_branch)
            )

if db(db.bank_master.id>0).count() == 0:
    db.bank_master.truncate()
    db.bank_branch.truncate()

    db.bank_master.insert(name='State Bank')
    db.bank_master.insert(name='Central Bank')
    db.bank_master.insert(name='Canara Bank')

    db.bank_branch.insert(name='Austin',bank=1)
    db.bank_branch.insert(name='Dallas',bank=1)
    db.bank_branch.insert(name='Chicago',bank=2)
    db.bank_branch.insert(name='Washington',bank=2)
    db.bank_branch.insert(name='Florida',bank=3)
    db.bank_branch.insert(name='Delhi',bank=3)

cascade = CascadingSelect(db.bank_master,db.bank_branch)
db.case_master.bank_branch.widget = cascade.widget
```

This is the controller:

```
def index():
    form = SQLFORM(db.case_master)  
    return dict(form=form)
```

And this is the view `index.html`:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h1>Test for Cascade</h1>
<h3>{{=form}}</h3>
```

This is the error ticket:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\web2py\gluon\restricted.py", line 219, in restricted
exec(ccode, environment)
File "C:/web2py/applications/cascade_3/controllers/default.py", line 64, in <module>
File "C:\web2py\gluon\globals.py", line 419, in <lambda>
self._caller = lambda f: f()
File "C:/web2py/applications/cascade_3/controllers/default.py", line 9, in index
form = SQLFORM(db.case_master)
File "C:\web2py\gluon\sqlhtml.py", line 1505, in __init__
inp = field.widget(field, default)
File "C:/web2py/applications/cascade_3/models/cascade_widget.py", line 26, in widget
for opt in options]
File "C:\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\objects.py", line 96, in __getitem__
raise KeyError
KeyError
```

The CascadingSelect widget works perfectly when the models used by [mfreeze](http://www.web2pyslices.com/person/show/mrfreeze) is tweaked by adding dummy fields, but somehow when I use my own models as above, the `KeyError` crops up. Can anyone help in locating my error?

Comment: Are you sure the code is _exactly_ as shown above? In particular, I notice you have commented out the definition of the `defendant1_bank_branch` field, yet later you make an assignment to the `widget` attribute of that field (that does not appear to be the cause of your error but makes me wonder if there are other differences between the above and your real code -- in particular, are the `format` arguments of your tables and other field names exactly as above)?

Comment: I noticed that later. But even a barebones model almost identical to that of the widget creator is giving the same error. The original post is updated with the new code. I made a new application to check that the error is not migration-related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [code](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1410/cascading-drop-down-lists) for the `CascadingSelect` widget includes the following:

```
        opts = [OPTION(format % opt,_value=opt.id,
                             _parent=opt[str(parent)] if parent else '0') \
                              for opt in options]
```

The `KeyError` is the result of `opt[str(parent)]` on the second pass through the `for` loop. In that case, `opt` is a `Row` from the `db.bank_branch` table, and the value of `str(parent)` is `"bank_master"` (i.e., the name of the first table). The value of `parent` is set near the end of the `for` loop at:

```
        parent = table
```

Of course, there is no `bank_master` field in `db.bank_branch` (instead, the reference field is simply named `"bank"`). So, the widget code expects the name of the reference field in the second table to be the same as the name of the first table. In other words, instead of:

```
    Field('bank', db.bank_master)
```

it expects:

```
    Field('bank_master', db.bank_master)
```

which is a common convention when naming reference fields in web2py.

So, you can either rename the reference field so it works with the current widget code, or you can modify the code to accommodate alternative reference field names (probably by adding an argument allowing you to specify the name explicitly).

Comment: Thanks a ton, Anthony.